# USPS taking too long to deliver tax returns [US Taxes]

Tags: united-states, income-tax, postal-order

I used USPS First-Class Mail with tracking to send my State and Federal Tax returns. It's been 10 days and the tracking site has a **In Transit, Arriving Late** status.
What happens if USPS fails to deliver or loses my tax returns?

Comment: Do you owe money?  Was it included with the tax returns?

Comment: Just FYI: tracking service is not considered "proof of mailing" by the IRS, only certified mail. So if a dispute arises, you won't have acceptable evidence that you mailed it on time.

Comment: I have a <$10 refund from IRS and nothing due/refund from State. USPS store added a label with postmark date of April 18 on my tax return envelope (which was 2022's last date to file tax return).

Comment: If USPS does manage to lose (or destroy) your Federal return, which is uncommon, you can just file another copy -- you did save a copy, right? With no balance due, you actually have until 3 years after the nominal deadline -- April 15 2025 (or next business day) -- with no penalty. But getting years out of order is bad, so if your 2022 income will require filing, you really should get 2021 filed before say February 2023. I believe all states are the same, but don't know for sure and anyway you didn't identify yours.

Answer (score 6):

IRS uses the postmark date rather than the delivery date.

From [IRS Topic No. 301](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc301), second paragraph:

> Your return is considered filed on time if the envelope is properly
> addressed, has enough postage, is postmarked, and is deposited in the
> mail by the due date. If you file electronically, the date and time in
> your time zone when your return is transmitted controls whether your
> return is filed timely. You will later receive an electronic
> acknowledgement that the IRS has accepted your electronically filed
> return.

Comment: The postmark date is April 18, 2022; which was the last date for 2022 for filing tax returns.